# jdk9 maven compilationa error: module reads package from both A and B

Tags: java-9, springfox

maven compilation error:

```
module 'my.demo' reads package 'springfox.documentation.service' from both 'springfox.core' and 'springfox.spi'
```

Is it possible to solve split package problem from dependencies?